# Tablas salen en inglés

Tags: javascript

me han hecho una aplicación con codeigniter y mediante editor he cambiado todo el texto y lo he puesto en inglés.

Pero tiene tablas y la información del tipo "showing 1 of 2 entries" o "search records" o la paginación NEXT PREVIOUS no consigo encontrarla para cambiarla a español.

Creo que tiene que ver algo con un unos archivos js, pero no encuentro donde están. Alguien sabe de qué hablo y cómo podría traducir esos textos a español?

Comment: Esas tablas a las que te refieres son de la librería datatables?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la solución en [este enlace](https://unipython.com/traducir-codeigniter-al-espanol/)

Necesitas los archivos con las traducciones (si es que no los tienes). Los puedes conseguir en [GitHub](https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations).

Incluyes la carpeta **spanish** en el directorio `application/language` del proyecto, y a continuación en el archivo `application/config/config.php` cambias el idioma a spanish como se muestra en la siguiente linea de código:

```
$config['language'] = 'spanish';
```

Answer (score 0):

Es algo que suele pasar cuando se trabaja con la librería `DataTables`, [en este enlace](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/) podrás encontrar toda la guía de internacionalización (i18n) y el listado de textos ya traducidos al español, en general sería algo similar a lo siguiente dentro del archivo donde instancias las tablas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "language": {
                "url": "dataTables.spanish.lang"
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```